# Could some one check for me if my unit test for the FillUpWater is correct

Tags: c#

Could someone tell me i this is a correct unit test for FillUpContainer()?

```
namespace CoffeeMaker
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class WaterContainer
    {
        //private WaterContainer WaterC; 
        WaterContainer WaterC = new WaterContainer(0);
        int level = WaterC.Level;

        [TestMethod()]
        public void FillUpWaterTest() 
        {                                      
            if (WaterC.Level == 0)
            {
                bool result;
               result = WaterC.FillUpWater();                
            }
            level.Equals(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no assertions, so no, I would say its not correct. Also we can't see what WaterContainer.FillUpWater does, so we can't say that its comprehensive. Tests should have a defined goal, to test a specific section of code within a method. I have one class I'm working on now that has 120 tests, roughly 4-5 tests per method.

Comment: Isn't level.Equals(5); the last code the Assert? must i write 'Assert' for it to be valid?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. `level.Equals(5)` is not an assertion, it's just an expression, the result of which you throw away by not assigning to anything.

A better test might look something like this:

```
[TestClass()]
public class WaterContainer
{        
    [TestMethod()]
    public void WhenWaterContainerIsEmpty_FillingItUp_CausesCorrectWaterLevel() 
    {                                      
        // arrange
        WaterContainer water = new WaterContainer(0);
        // act
        water.FillUpWater();
        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(5, water.Level);
    }
}
```

Notice the method name describes what's being tested, and the test is self-contained (all local variables).

The `Assert` statement will cause the test to actually fail if the water level is not correct.

Comment: Good method name, shows how you should name test methods. Only thing I would change is to use Assert.AreEqual<int>, doesn't technically matter but shows that you are expecting an integer return value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
level.Equals(5);
```

I believe you want this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(5, WaterC.Level);
```

This will cause the unit test to fail if `WaterC.Level != 5`.

Comment: OK, i get it. The FillUpWater() function i was to test is as follows?
public bool FillUpWater()
        {
            WaterTap tap = new WaterTap();

            if (tap.FillUpContainer())
            {
                Level = 5;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void FillUpWater()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

Comment: Looks like that should work.  Alternatively, you could check if the return value is `True` by calling `Assert.IsTrue(tap.FillUpWater());`

Comment: I'm getting an error; Don't you Think the waterTap needs to be initialised in the test class and used in the Act [method]?

Comment: I think, there should be a waterContainer object and a WaterTap object. waterTap fills the WaterContainer and thereafter Assert whether the waterContainer object is full. Is my reasoning ok?

Comment: Ya, that sounds like a reasonable test

Comment: [TestClass()]
        public class WaterContainer
        {
            [TestMethod()]
            public void WhenWaterContainerIsEmpty_FillingItUp_CausesCorrectWaterLevel()    // Uppgift 4:  
            {                                                                            
                WaterContainer waterC = new WaterContainer(0);
                WaterTap tap = new WaterTap();
                
                waterC = tap.FillUpContainer();
                
                Assert.IsTrue(tap.FillUpContainer());
            }
        }